# JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) when using google api

Tags: python, python-requests, google-api

I'm using google api in python. My purpose is find and download any image similar with my image. This my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 971, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Administrator\.vscode\tempCodeRunnerFile.python", line 27, in <module> 
    results = response.json()["items"]
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 975, in json
    raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)
requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

What was wrong with my code? I noticed `response` was return `<Response [400]>`, i guess it is problem with my code. How to fix it? Any help is appreciated. Below is the code:

```python
import requests
import urllib.request

# Replace YOUR_API_KEY with your actual API key
api_key = "YOUR_API_KEY"

# Load the image you want to search for
# image_data = open("path/to/image.jpg", "rb").read()
image_data = open("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Downloads\\theme\\3f559715-f407-47de-8540-1cd9e4fdc56c.jpg", "rb").read()

# Send the request to the Google Search API's "similar images" feature
response = requests.post(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1/similar?",
    params={
        "key": api_key,
        # "cx": "YOUR_CX_VALUE",  # Replace YOUR_CX_VALUE with your actual CX value
        "cx": "d47119ff66e004d6b",
    },
    headers={
        "Content-Type": "image/jpeg",
    },
    data=image_data,
)
# print(response) -><Response [400]>

# Get the search results from the response
results = response.json()["items"]

# Iterate through the search results and download the images
for result in results:
    image_url = result["link"]
    image_filename = image_url.split("/")[-1]
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(image_url, image_filename)
    print(f"Downloaded image: {image_filename}")
```

Comment: Your response is 400 ergo, there is no JSON.
If you can provide us with the API documentation for the Google API you are trying to use, we might be able to help.

Comment: i was read a tutorial from [here](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/introduction) to create api key. Has it been of any help to you?

Comment: It kinda looks like the request should be a `GET` and the parameters should be query params.

Comment: You might want to replace your API key. Posting that publicly may be very unsafe.

Comment: @realFishSam i was edit now

Comment: @enslaved_programmer what do you mind? should i replace `requests` become `get`? Can you explain it?